# access to ExpressJs server hosted on my Pi from my website

Tags: api, express, raspberry-pi

I am currently building a smart home project. I have express running on my Pi with my data stored locally. I would like to access it from a website using queries. The API is very basic but works for my needs.

My question is: How to connect a website to my local data on my Pi?

Comment: by port forwarding on your internet connection or https://ngrok.com/

Comment: Ok, and in my router configuration, what am I supposed to use as start and end port ? does it matter ?

Comment: ok I set up a basic https connexion on 443

Comment: I used 192.168.0.17 with the port 443, and by doing .listen(443,"0.0.0.0") with node, I can access it on my pi @0.0.0.0.443 but it doesn"t work on any other computer

Comment: check firewall settings. also you should use external ip to access from other computers

Comment: I am hosting express in a pi, so I don't have any firewall I think, ufw is not even recognized. the website whatismyip gives me my public IPv4, but when I try to access it, I cannot reach the page

Comment: pi os is linux based probably has selinux if it is on you may set it to off. also please add screenshot of your port forwarding settings.

Comment: It looks like a basic networking issue. You need to make sure that both the Raspberry Pi and the web server (or any other clients to consume the APIs available on the Pi) can see each other on the network.

Comment: I succed accessing my database hosted on my pi from my laptop using the local adress and the wifi, but when I try to access it with the external ip of the pi, using the port 443 that I set in my rooter, I cannot reach the API. My IP looks like this 84.*.**.**

Comment: by default, pi doesn't have a firewall, so I don't think it's a firewall problem

Comment: Maybe the problem is that my rooter uses dynamic IP, which could result in random change of IP even if I forwarded the 443 port ?

Answer (score 0):

[here is the description on my rooter's settigns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH3DK.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH3DK.png]

Comment: sorry I'm kinda new on stackoverflow so I don't have the reputation to have my picture fully displayed, you'll have to follow the link

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was wrong configuring the port forwarding, I omitted to redirect to the local adress of my Pi. It gives: start port :80 End port:80  Protocol: both TCP and UDP and local IP adress, the one of my PI, which is 192.168.0.21